# TKINTER : How to keep track of Dynamically Created Buttons and action something when it is pressed

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to find a solution for dynamically created buttons. For e.g. my app is creating 5 buttons dynamically and each button have different functionality within a callback function.
what I am trying to do is, if Button 5 is pressed, how would I compare it in function if Button 5 is clicked. I am not creating separate function for each and every button. There is one single function, within that I have logic for every button.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

masterFrame = Frame(root,bg = 'orange',height =300,width =600)
masterFrame.grid(row = 0,column = 0,sticky ='nsew')

ButtonString = ['DashBoard','Report','Tools','Settings','About']

# How should I compare what function to call when Button object is passed
def viewButton(btn):
    
    def DashBoard():
        pass
    
    def Report():
        pass
    
    def Tools():
        pass
    
#This is what I want to do    
    
    # if btn == 'DashBoard:
    #    DashBoard()
        
    # if btn == 'Report:
    #    Report()

for index,btn in enumerate(ButtonString):
    #Button text remains same for all Buttons which is "View"
    btn = Button(masterFrame,text = 'View',command = viewButton)
    btn.grid(row = index ,column = 0,padx =10,pady =10)

root.rowconfigure(0,weight = 1)
root.columnconfigure(0,weight =1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Show us the code, usually you will store them in a loop.

Comment: @CoolCloud how do You expect to store something in a loop? more like in a list

Comment: @Matiiss Oh my bad, I meant usually it is inside a loop, then store it in a list

Comment: @CoolCloud Entire code will be too lengthy and complicated but here is the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
root = Tk()

masterFrame = Frame(root, bg='orange', height=300, width=600)
masterFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

ButtonString = ['DashBoard', 'Report', 'Tools', 'Settings', 'About']


# Calling this function from somewhere else via Queue
def viewButton(btn):
    print(btn)
    def DashBoard():
        pass

    def Report():
        pass

    def Tools():
        pass


# This is what I want to do

# if btn == 'DashBoard:
#    DashBoard()

# if btn == 'Report:
#    Report()

for index, btn_name in enumerate(ButtonString):
    btn = Button(masterFrame, text='View '+str(btn_name), command=partial(viewButton, btn_name))
    btn.grid(row=index, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

you can use above code to check which button is pressed. You can change arguments according to your need.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Abhishek but Button text is "View" for all buttons and I cannot have a different text for every Button. That's the issue.

Comment: Change button text as you want There will be no problem. The code will run fine then also. I just renamed them to easily distinguish between them

Comment: I see, what are you proposing. I tried that and it worked fine. Thanks Abhishek.

Comment: Welcome Anni 